# Weird behavior of std::is_sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, compare, assert

I'm learning assertions in c++, and I came across weird behaviour of std::is_sorted.

Given a comparator(c), and unsorted vector(v) of std::strings. I use std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comparator). and then call std::is_sorted with the same arguments. And the outcome is false, why so ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>
int main(){
    auto comparator([](std::string a , std::string b) {return a.length() - b.length();} );
    std::vector<std::string> v {"y" , "yyyy" , "yy" ,
                                 "yy" , "yyyyyyy" , "yyy"};
    assert(false == std::is_sorted(v.begin() , v.end(),comparator));
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),comparator);
    assert(true == std::is_sorted(v.begin() , v.end(),comparator));
}
```

Comment: Your comparator does not implement a strict weak ordering.   `sort()` and `is_sorted()` therefore have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your predicate is not working properly. If you intend to sort by string length, you need

```
auto comparator([](std::string a , std::string b) {return a.length() < b.length();} );
```

The original predicate you posted returns the string length difference, which is of integral type and can be converted to `bool` when invoked by `std::sort`, and does result in `true` for everything different than `0`, `false` otherwise.  Hence, every non-equal string lengths result in the predicate being evaluated to `true`, and sequence elements with different string length would be infinitely swapped due to the predicate being "true" all the time. This results in undefined behavior.

The terminology here is that the predicate must implement a "strict weak ordering", which is documented e.g. on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Thanks to @FrançoisAndrieux and @Peter for the comments with this regard.

Also consider passing the arguments by `const std::string&` or `std::string_view` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: The short explanation (which you may want to expand on) of why the OP's predicate doesn't work is that it doesn't define a strict weak ordering - whereas `sort()` and `is_sorted()` assume it does.   Your explanation about returning a value that can be converted to `bool` doesn't really cover that.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard (*28.7 Sorting and related operations*)

> 2 Compare is a function object type (23.14). **The return value of the
>   function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 7), yields true if the first
>   argument of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise.**
>   Compare comp is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering
>   relation. It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant
>   function through the dereferenced iterator.

This lambda expression

```
auto comparator([](std::string a , std::string b) {return a.length() - b.length();} );
```

always returns (contextually converted value) `true` if lengths of two strings are unequal.

So for this vector

```
std::vector<std::string> v {"y" , "yyyy" , "yy" ,
                             "yy" , "yyyyyyy" , "yyy"};
```

the lambda-expression returns `false` for adjacent elements `"yy"` and `"yy"` at position `2` and `3`.

If for example you will place an intermediate value between positions 2 and 3 as for example

```
std::vector<std::string> v {"y" , "yyyy" , "yy" , "y",
                             "yy" , "yyyyyyy" , "yyy"};
```

then the first assertion

```
assert(false == std::is_sorted(v.begin() , v.end(),comparator));
```

fails.

Thus you need correctly to define the comparison function. For example

```
auto comparator( []( const std::string &a , const std::string &b ) 
                 {
                     return a.length() < b.length(); 
                 } );
```

Also the parameters of the lambda expression should be constant references.

Take into account that if your compiler supports C++ 17 then you could also rewrite the lambda expression the following way

```
auto comparator( []( const std::string &a , const std::string &b ) 
                 {
                     return std::size( a ) < std::size( b ); 
                 } );
```